# How to reference a bean which is being imported from another source?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a `wireup-A.xml` as

```
<bean id="xml-saver" class="com.org.blah.XMLSaver"/>
```

and another `wireup-B.xml` as

```
<import resource="classpath:com/A/wireup-A.xml" />

    <bean id="save-xml" class="com.org.post.SaveXML">
        <constructor-arg ref="xml-saver"/>
    </bean>
```

**Question**

How can `ref="xml-saver"` can refer to bean which is in `import resource`?
It is saying now that `can not resolve bean xml-saver`

Comment: Can you use camelCase: `xmlSaver` and `saveXml` naming convention in both files? Don't think it's the problem, but give it a try, such approach typically works.

Comment: I was doing it wrong, the path I was giving was incorrect, now it is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I made the reference to correct path everything was good

```
<import resource="classpath:com/A/blah/wireup-A.xml" />
```